# Rxjs 6 Pipe not working in code

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am using code from a previous Rxjs version codebase that connects to Firestore, I changed everything to use the correct imports and added the .pipe(map). I am getting an saying "[ts] Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'DocumentChangeAction[]." Here is my function that is giving me the issue. Thank you.

```
  private mapAndUpdate(col: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>) {       
  var values;


if (this._done.value || this._loading.value) { return };

this._loading.next(true)

// Map snapshot with doc ref (needed for cursor)
return col.snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(tap(arr => {
    values = arr.pipe(
      map((snap: any) => {
      const data = snap.payload.doc.data();
      const doc = snap.payload.doc;
      return { ...data, doc }; 
    }))
  ));

    // If prepending, reverse array
    values = this.query.prepend ? values.reverse() : values

    // update source with new values, done loading
    this._data.next(values)
    this._loading.next(false)

    // no more values, mark done
    if (!values.length) {
      this._done.next(true)
    }
})
.take(1)
.subscribe()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is inside `tap` operator:

```js
tap(arr => {
  values = arr.pipe(
    map((snap: any) => {
    const data = snap.payload.doc.data();
    const doc = snap.payload.doc;
    return { ...data, doc }; 
  }))
));
```

`arr` is a array of `DocumentChangeAction`, not Observable. You have to map each item. The result is already computed, so no need to do with Observable again

```js
tap(arr => {
  values = arr.map((snap: any) => {
    const data = snap.payload.doc.data();
    const doc = snap.payload.doc;
    return { ...data, doc }; 
  });
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported these?

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, scan, take, switchMap, startWith, tap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Yes I have. Visual Code doesn't even recognize that "take" is being used by the code because of, I believe, this error.

Comment: what is the angular version

Comment: The Angular version is 6.0.8

Comment: i dont see any issue